# Toggle visibility for React Native elements?

Tags: react-native

In React Native, is there a way to toggle visibility of an element?

For example:

```
<Text visibility={this.state.isVisible}>Visibility depends on state</Text>
```

Answer (score 3):

this might be crude but it works.

under render

```
var visibletext = null;
if (this.state.isVisible) {
   visibletext = (<Text>Visibility depends on state</Text>);
}
```

then, under return part

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   {visibletext}
</View>
```

Comment: I don't think that would dynamically update when the variable is changed, would it?

Comment: If you update the state with the `setState` method, this would automatically re-render the component. Also, simply *not* rendering a component (i.e. the <Text> view in this case) and returning null instead seems to be pretty much the way to achieve the thing you want in React as well, so I assume this to be the same in React Native.

Comment: Also, this answer would remove the element entirely (like display:none), it wouldn't leave it as invisible but still taking space in the DOM

Comment: This would make the element both invisible AND intangible. Not normally that useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this. See the [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) guide at the React.js website, which explains different options.

One simple way is to use the [&& operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) inline:

```js
{this.state.isVisible &&
  <Text>Something</Text>
}
```

---

Note that with the conditional rendering approach, if you have (for example) some views *centered vertically*, this views will *suddenly* move up or down when the text appears (to give room for the new view). Another approach that avoids this jump is to either change the text color or set the text to empty string:

```js
// Change the text color
<Text style={this.state.isVisible ? {color: 'black'} : {color: 'white'}}>Something</Text>

// Set text to empty string
<Text>{this.state.isVisible ? "Something" : ""}</Text>
```

Changing the color of the text is the best way to make sure that the other views don't suddenly move when showing the text, given that the text is already occupying the layout space it needs.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this without using state?

Comment: @Zack you can do this without state. All you need is a boolean. To get the boolean you can use a prop instead of state, or create a function that returns a boolean depending on something.